# How to convert "Hashmap values of List type" into Set?

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap, guava

How to get concatenate "List of values" in a Map to create single list and then to pass into another method:

```
Map<Long,List<Long>> activities = new HashMap();
for(Something s: something){
  activities .put(prosessLongID, listOfSubProcesses);
} //There are 5 something and for each there are 2 List of Subprocesses which makes 10 Subprocesses
```

I want to concatenate list of Subprocesses from above Map to create a Set:

```
 ImmutableSet.copyOf(listOfSubProcesses_ForAllSomething) //com.google.common.collect
```

Is there any method in Map which returns all List of SubProcesses in single list which i could pass in above method?

Note: I got response from @Eran on Java 8 and thanks for that. But please consider Java 6 and solution other then looping. I have facility of APache Commons and Guava.  :)

Comment: there is a method `Collection<V> values()`, all you need to do is check the documentation...

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use Java 8 Stream, use Guava's [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) (and [`Map#values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) as @Lukas mentioned in comment):

```
ImmutableSet<Long> subprocessIds = FluentIterable.from(activities.values())
        .transformAndConcat(Functions.identity())
        .toSet();
```

[`FluentIterable#transformAndConcat`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat(com.google.common.base.Function)) is equivalent to `Stream#flatMap`, identity function does effectively nothing, so it's direct translation from @Eran's Java 8 answer to Guava and Java 7.

Alternatively you can use [`Iterables#concat`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)) to achieve the same result without fluent calls:

```
ImmutableSet<Long> subprocessIds = ImmutableSet.copyOf(
        Iterables.concat(activities.values()));
```

---

**But** what you really want to do is use proper data structure, here: [`ListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) (or maybe even [`SetMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html)?):

```
ListMultimap<Long, Long> activities = ArrayListMultimap.create();
activities.putAll(1L, ImmutableList.of(2L, 32L, 128L));
activities.put(3L, 4L);
activities.put(3L, 8L);
```

because [`Multimap#values()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#values()) gives you what you need (as `Collection` view, so copy into `Set` if neccessary):

```
ImmutableSet<Long> subprocessIds = ImmutableSet.copyOf(activities.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 Streams API to collect all the `List`s into a single `Stream` and then into a single `List` :

```
List<Long> listOfSubProcesses_ForAllSomething = 
    activities.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks.But i am not using Java-8 as of now. Upvote for solution for Java 8. What about Java 6

Comment: @fatherazrael Then use a loop and addAll to add the elements of each list to the single list.

Comment: That i understand. Isn't any shortcut or library methods in Guava or Apache Common?

Comment: @fatherazrael There might be. I'm not familiar with Guava.